# Как взять из списка текст по порядку?

Tags: python

```
k = []
inp = int(input("Сколько повторов : "))

while inp != 0:
    information = input("Информация : ")
    if information == "exit":
        inp = 0

    else:
        k.append(information)
        inp -= 1
```

Как сделать, чтобы из списка k извлекались все переменные по порядку и генерировалось такое :

```
>>> Информация : 1
>>> Информация : 2
...
>>> Информация : 1000
print(output)
>>> python 1 python 2 [...] python 999 python 1000
```

Comment: Так в чём проблеме то? Вам надо чтобы в конце весь списка вивелся по порядку верно? Или же чтобы он отсортировался от меньшего числа до большего, а потом уже вивелся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
k = []
inp = int(input("Сколько повторов : "))

while inp != 0:
    information = input("Информация : ")
    if information == "exit":
        inp = 0

    else:
        k.append(information)
        inp -= 1

for information in k:
    print(f"python {information} ", end="")
print()
```

также можно  переделать первый цикл

```
k = []
inp = int(input("Сколько повторов : "))

for _ in range(inp):
    information = input("Информация : ")
    if information == "exit":
        break
    k.append(information)
        

for information in k:
    print(f"python {information} ", end="")
print()
```